# elasticsearch fails to start when adding path.repo

Tags: elasticsearch, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to setup a 3 nodes cluster over 3 virtual machines (Ubuntu 16.04) of Elasticsearch (5.1).
The cluster worked fine, and then I added the path.repo -

```
path.repo : ['/mount/backups']
```

But when I restart Elasticsearch after changing elasticsearch.yml - it fails to restart.
any idea what can cause this?

Thanks ahead.

Comment: Can you share the Elasticsearch log output?

Comment: thanks for your comment. I wasn't aware where ES log is. It seems that I tried to write to a directory where I didn't have write permissions.

Comment: yap. I changes the permissions and now it is working. thanks